# Performance implications of readdir_r deprecation?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, deprecated, readdir

When I was recompiling my FUSE filesystem on new workstation I noticed deprecation warnings regarding `readdir_r`. Since `readdir` is not MT Safe and requires own synchronization I'm a bit puzzled.

I'm not sure what exactly is not MT Safe - is it `readdir` alone or is it entire process of reading certain directory until the end? It seems that standard tries to justify this decision by pointing out that `readdir` is MT Safe if it's called on different directories but that's obviously not safe assumption if your "program" is multi-user overlay FUSE filesystem. So should I put entire directory reading procedure in critical section or just individual `readdir` calls?

Both cases to be honest sound to me pretty bad from performance standpoint - are my concerns valid or are there some other bottlenecks in Linux kernel that make it impossible anyways to perform parallel read on single directory by more than one process/thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the current POSIX.1 specification (POSIX.1-2008), readdir(3) is
>             not required to be thread-safe.  However, in modern
>             implementations (including the glibc implementation), concurrent
>             calls to readdir(3) that specify different directory streams are
>             thread-safe.

The man page says it's thread safe (assuming you are using glibc, which I think is a fair assumption on Linux) -- provided you are using different directory *streams* - not different directory.

A directory stream is the DIR * parameter to readdir.